# Is there any reaction between amines and AgNO3?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, reactivity, amines

I found a question in a book about the reaction between $\ce{AgNO3}$ and aromatic/aliphatic amines, but I couldn't find any information about
it. What should be the expected reaction mechanism and products formed in this reaction?

Comment: Hint: It is easier to find what happens with $\ce{Ag+}$ and $\ce{NH3}$.

Comment: I don't think [this](http://jcsp.org.pk/ArticleUpload/3413-15385-1-RV.pdf) is the intended reaction but it might be of interest.

Comment: @bon makes an interesting point. Ag(I) is a pretty good oxidant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this reaction between amines and silver nitrate:[image: reaction]

Comment: I think this is the reaction I was looking for

Comment: Note: aromatic amines behave differently (obviously)

Comment: Any link to valid references?